# Nativescript android.net.Uri.parse

Tags: java, android, webview, uri, nativescript

I am trying to enable file upload in a webview for android using nativescript.

The problem i am facing is when i am calling my file path callback function "onReceiveValue" where i am supposed to pass by a "android.net.Uri[]".

```
var mFilePathCallback: android.webkit.ValueCallback<android.net.Uri[]>;
```

This is how the array is made:

```
let results: android.net.Uri[] = [];
let dataString = data.getDataString();
results.push(android.net.Uri.parse(dataString));
```

And then the call:

```
mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
```

The error i am getting:
Error: Cannot convert array to Ljava/lang/Object; at index 0

I am trying to make this implementation: https://github.com/OpenGeeksMe/Android-File-Chooser/blob/master/app/src/main/java/it/floryn90/webapp/MainActivity.java

Comment: let dataString = data.getDataString();
Can you please tell me from where you have got the 'data' ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code for generating an array should look like this:

```
let results = Array.create(android.net.Uri, 1);
let dataString = data.getDataString();
results[0] = android.net.Uri.parse(dataString);
```

Where the `1` in it is the number of elements the array is going to hold...